# HOC for JSX element

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a HOC function that would wrap a list item, do some conditional checking and return this JSX element if condition pass or being wrapped by another component if fail.
Here is the part of the code inside the `render` method:

```
const workspaceListItem = (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ListItem button onClick={() => this.handleOpening(workspace)}>
          <Avatar>
            <WorkIcon />
          </Avatar>
          <ListItemText
            inset
            primary={workspace.name}
            secondary={`Created: ${workspace.createdTime.split("T")[0]}`}
          />
          {expandButton}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={isOpen} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          {groupList}
        </Collapse>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
    const WithToolTipWorkspace = withToolTip(workspaceListItem);
    return WithToolTipWorkspace;
```

I assign this JSX element to `workspaceListItem` variable then I call my HOC `withToolTip()` and pass `workspaceListItem` as argument. 
Here is the `withToolTip` definition:

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

function withToolTip(WrappedComponent) {
  return function WrappedWithToolTip(props) {
    return props.parent.children === undefined ||
      props.parent.children.length === 0 ? (
      <Tooltip title="Children of this element does not exist">
        {WrappedComponent}
      </Tooltip>
    ) : (
      { WrappedComponent }
    );
  };
}

export default withToolTip;
```

When I compile it I get React error

`Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I'm a beginner when it comes to React and still learning.

Thank you for any tips I would really appreciate it.

Edit:

I did what estus suggested like so:

```
return <WithToolTipWorkspace parent={workspace} />;
```

and inside HOC

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

function withToolTip(WrappedComponent) {
  return function WrappedWithToolTip(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return props.parent.children === undefined ||
      props.parent.children.length === 0 ? (
      <Tooltip title="Children of this element does not exist">
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </Tooltip>
    ) : (
      <WrappedComponent {...props} />
    );
  };
}

export default withToolTip;
```

now error changed to this one:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: <Fragment />. Did you accidentally export a JSX literal instead of a component?
```

Most probably because I'm passing JSX element to HOC and not a component but how can I do it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The error explains the problem:

> This may happen if you return a `Component` instead of `<Component />` from render

An element should be created from `WrappedComponent`. HOC likely needs to pass props to it as well:

```
return props.parent.children === undefined ||
  props.parent.children.length === 0 ? (
  <Tooltip title="Children of this element does not exist">
    <WrappedComponent {...props}>
  </Tooltip>
) : (
    <WrappedComponent {...props}>    
);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying  estus.